# Samsung s7 password locked - can't get onto phone

Tags: lock-screens, google, password, samsung-galaxy-s7

today I authorized a payment through Google pay on my phone. I've always avoided this and now I know why I never wanted to pay through Google. As I made this purchase it prompted me to create a phone safety option (either a pattern, password, or fingerprint), and I didn't really understand why that was necessary to authorize payment (no other payment form was given as an option), but I went with it and created a password. I remember this password. Now after my phone went to sleep, it wanted me to enter a password, since I apparently enabled this feature (hate it). I entered the password I created during this transaction, and there is no 'enter' button or prompt. Just the password box, and 'emergency call.' However I tried hitting 'done' on my phone keypad and it says incorrect password. Several times, I know it's what I created it with. SO... I went ahead and tried my actual Google password for the email account I used to make the earlier purchase. Still can't get onto my phone. I'm sorry, but what the hell ???  Can anyone help me with this and maybe a way I don't need to factory reset and lose everything (pics, texts, apps, contacts (I'm not sure if they're Google backed up)) ?   All I wanted to do was relax and watch something I really like.  I'm also having trouble troubleshooting on my computer because it's slow... and I can't call anyone.  WHY

Comment: remove the SIM card. this way you can be sure not to mixing up SIM pin and screen lock. maybe the password is too long and doesn't fit? i am sorry to say but all your data is lost. you can try to set new password from PC with [Find My Mobile](https://findmymobile.samsung.com) or [Find My Device](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) but people report this method doesn't work. Your only chance left is enter the correct password

Answer (score 0):

If you go through your computer and change the password it makes you able to initialize a new password and unlock it manualy when you do so and log off your computer after turning your phone back on so yes turn your phon.off before changing it on your cpu
. I hacked a phome back to myself this way but i forgot the password and initaly im forever locked out of that phone unless i figure out the newest password that google took away from me! Contact google AFTER! YOU do this so your account dosent get locked due to them thinking its being hacked!